# Swift - Can't understand the contentSize of a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Hi I have set in my storyboard a `UIScrollView` (of the same size of the view) and ctrl-dragged it in my code.
Now I have created a button programmatically using a simple algorithm of mine.
I then tried to

`println(button.frame.origin.y)`

which printed **1700**.
Then I tried

`println(button.frame.height)`

which printed **142.2** (also coming from the algorithm). So the heigh I would like to reach while scrolling is `1700 + 142.2 = 1842.2`
So i tried to hardcode the content size in this way

`self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.bounds.size.width, height:2000)`

But when I run the app I can scroll no more than the middle of the button, which is in numbers
`1700 + 142.2/2 = 1771.1`

Why the heck is that?
I did all this to try to understand how this `UIScrollView` works but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT**
Added a screenshot.
Inside the bubbles there is the `button.frame.origin.y` value. That's the max I can scroll leaving the screen untouched.

[image]

Comment: Some screenshots might help us understand what might be wrong.

Comment: @nhgrif added a screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably to do with scroll view insets - a mechanism where the edges of the content always appear under the navigation and toolbar.

You either need to manually account for this by reading the contentInset property of the scroll view, or using interface builder.

[image: /Users/apple/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~Preview/Documents/Untitled 3.png]

[image]

Scroll view Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Comment: Where do I find that in my storyboard?

Comment: It's a setting on navigation controllers, not on the scroll view.

Comment: Found it but it's already checked. Anyway it's possible it's caused by the use of `Size Classes` ?